# How to write the amplitude for mixing inducing loop diagrams?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams

Consider figure T1-i-2-A, on pag. 8, on [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.09537).

It generates a neutrino mass through the mixing of left and right-components of a fermion through its mass term: this is represented by the cross in the internal fermion line. The scalar mixing is also needed, in the upper line (the external scalar lines are a representation of the scalar bilinear term generated by their vevs).

How to write an explicit amplitude for this type of diagram? How many propagators are there? What is the mass that appears on the propagators (since these particles are not mass eigenstates)?